# Spring Boot Thymeleaf 3 external javascript template configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a spring boot application which is working as an OAuth2 client.

I'm using Thymeleaf 3 as template engine. These are the Thymeleaf 3 related dependencies in my build.gradle.

```
compile('org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf:3.0.1.RELEASE')
compile('org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-spring4:3.0.1.RELEASE')
compile('nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-layout-dialect:2.0.4')
compile('org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4:3.0.1.RELEASE')
```

It makes no difference if I reference the dependencies like this:

```
ext["thymeleaf.version"] = "3.0.2.RELEASE"
ext["thymeleaf-layout-dialect.version"] = "2.1.1"
dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf')
}
```

I want to be able to use Thymeleaf 3's HTML and Javascript template modes.
HTML mode works, but in javascript mode the messageSource is not working properly.

Here is my WebMvcConfiguration class:

```
@Configuration
public class WebMVCConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private static final String CHARACTER_ENCODING = "UTF-8";
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver htmlViewResolver() {
        ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine(htmlTemplateResolver()));
        resolver.setContentType("text/html");
        resolver.setCharacterEncoding(CHARACTER_ENCODING);
        resolver.setViewNames(new String[] {"*.html"});
        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver javascriptViewResolver() {
        ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine(javascriptTemplateResolver()));
        resolver.setContentType("application/javascript");
        resolver.setCharacterEncoding(CHARACTER_ENCODING);
        resolver.setViewNames(new String[] {"*.js"});
        return resolver;
    }

    private TemplateEngine templateEngine(ITemplateResolver templateResolver) {
        SpringTemplateEngine engine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        engine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver);
        return engine;
    }

    private ITemplateResolver htmlTemplateResolver() {
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver resolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        resolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        resolver.setPrefix("templates/");
        resolver.setCacheable(false);
        resolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
        resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        return resolver;
    }

    public ITemplateResolver javascriptTemplateResolver() {
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver resolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        resolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        resolver.setPrefix("classpath:/static/js/");
        resolver.setCacheable(false);
        resolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.JAVASCRIPT);
        // resolver.setSuffix(".js");
        return resolver;
    }
}
```

Please note that I had to use "classpath:/static/js/" in javascriptTemplateResolver, because when I used only "static/js/", I got the following exception:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/static/js/headerconfig.js]
```

Also I had to comment out setSuffix, because with it I get the following exception:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [static/js/typeutils.js.js] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

I think this already indicates the main problem but I can't figure out what may cause it.

---

I have a controller for handling javascript templates:

```
@Controller
public class JavascriptController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/js/{template}.js")
    public String jsMapping(@PathVariable("template") String template, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("myAttribute", "Attribute works!");
        return template;
    }
}
```

My messages.properties files are located in

- src/main/resources/messages.properties
- src/main/resources/messages_hu.properties

---

I have an HTML file in src/main/resources/templates/ folder, which references a javascript file like so:

```
<script th:src="@{js/typeutils.js}"></script>
```

The referenced javascript file (js/typeutils.js):

```
var a = [[${myAttribute}]];
var b = [[#{test}]];
console.log(a);
console.log(b);
```

When I run the application and check the javascript console, this is what's being printed out:

```
Attribute works!
??test_hu_HU??
```

So the model attribute was successfully passed to the javascript file, and the localization has been detected, but the message wasn't found for 'test'.
It seems as if the javascript template mode behaves completely different from HTML template mode.

How should if fix the javascript template mode config in order for it to process the messages.properties files, too?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you use inspect element in browser to check what value has in your template's script src tag

Comment: It replaces the script tag as if it was a normal script tag:
<script src="/rajos/js/typeutils.js"></script>
Though there's no type="text/javascript" attribute in it.

Comment: You have your js files in js folder inside static folder and your html in templates folder . right !. you can access your js file from template . like this: <script th:src="@{/js/typeutils.js}"></script> .. i have added `/` . pls try this

Comment: I have tried it but I have the same results: model attribute gets inserted but the message doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the solution (by looking through thymeleaf sourcecode), which might not be perfect, but it works!

Unlike the [example](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-thymeleaf-3) given by Baeldung, the following solved the problem for me:

```
@Configuration
public class WebMVCConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer, ApplicationContextAware {
    private static final String CHARACTER_ENCODING = "UTF-8";
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver htmlViewResolver() {
        ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        resolver.setContentType("text/html");
        resolver.setCharacterEncoding(CHARACTER_ENCODING);
        resolver.setViewNames(new String[] { "*.html" });
        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver javascriptViewResolver() {
        ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        resolver.setContentType("application/javascript");
        resolver.setCharacterEncoding(CHARACTER_ENCODING);
        resolver.setViewNames(new String[] { "*.js" });
        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        SpringTemplateEngine engine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        engine.setMessageSource(messageSource());
        engine.addTemplateResolver(htmlTemplateResolver());
        engine.addTemplateResolver(javascriptTemplateResolver());
        return engine;
    }

    private ITemplateResolver htmlTemplateResolver() {
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver resolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        resolver.setOrder(0);
        resolver.setCheckExistence(true);
        resolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        resolver.setPrefix("classpath:templates/");
        resolver.setCacheable(false);
        resolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
        resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        return resolver;
    }

    public ITemplateResolver javascriptTemplateResolver() {
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver resolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        resolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        resolver.setOrder(1);
        resolver.setCheckExistence(true);
        resolver.setPrefix("classpath:/static/js/");
        resolver.setCacheable(false);
        resolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.JAVASCRIPT);
        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource msgSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        msgSource.setAlwaysUseMessageFormat(false);
        msgSource.setBasename("messages");
        msgSource.setDefaultEncoding(CHARACTER_ENCODING);
        msgSource.setFallbackToSystemLocale(true);
        msgSource.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(false);
        return msgSource;
    }
}
```

Basically what happens is we set templateEngine to be a bean, so that we override ThymeleafDefaultConfiguration's default templateEngine implementation bean. This means that each time a template needs to be resolved, the same templateEngine will be used for sure.

We set the order of the htmlTemplateResolver to be 0, and the order of the javascriptTemplateResolver to be 1, so that we will try to resolve each template first in HTML template mode, then in Javascript mode.

It's important, too, that we set the checkExistence flag of the SpringResourceTemplateResolvers to true, because this way if a template can't be found, we will try with the next TemplateResolver.

There is one drawback of this solution, which is we will try to resolve javascript templates unnecessary in HTML mode first, then in JAVASCRIPT mode, so there is an extra step when resolving javascript resources.

I will try to solve the problem better but for now, this works for me.